# datagrid "Sorry an error occurred" when adding a new column

Tags: datagrid, xpages

I have a datagrid that is working but when I add another simple column, I the the "Sorry an error occurred" error message.  I've tried it for a couple of fields I have on the view and even reverted it back to what I had before.  It's still giving me this error.  I'd include code but I don't know what to include.  Does anyone know this issue?

Comment: What errors are displayed in Firebug? It sounds like a CSJS error.

Comment: No errors unless I'm not looking at it right.  Haven't used firebug much but nothing.

Comment: Got it working.  Didn't have the column on the view for the datagrid.